# Does Segment's Analytics.js have an Integration with Pinterest? (Without Segment.io)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, pinterest, segment-analytics

I'm wanting to use Segment's Analytics.js open source package (but not use their hosted solution segment.io) and I noticed that their hosted solution has an integration with Pinterest, but I can't seem to find it in Analytics.js.  Can you only get the Pinterest integration through their hosted solution?  If not, how can I use it when initializing Analytics.js?

Here is my current initialization (taken from this [helpful article](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/how-to-use-analytics-js-to-fix-your-analytics-code-and-achieve-metrics-nirvana))

```
analytics.load(function () {
    analytics.initialize({
        'Google Analytics': {
            trackingId: '{{ GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID }}'
        },
        'Mixpanel': {
            token: '{{ MIXPANEL_TOKEN }}',
            people: true
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Segment does have an integration with Pinterest (https://segment.com/docs/destinations/pinterest-tag/). However, this integration code is private and only available in the Segment hosted version.

Comment: Under my account on segment.com I have the Pinterest source setup and am using it.  But I wasn't able to find Pinterest in Analytics.js. https://imgur.com/a/HgEDC

Comment: Sorry for the delay. My mistake, we do in fact have a Pinterest integration (https://segment.com/docs/destinations/pinterest-tag/). Unfortunately this is a private integration and not available in the open source version. I would recommend you write in via support (https://segment.com/contact) so they can direct your request to the correct folks.